# How can I read an OCCURS structure using a CICS CONTAINER?

Tags: containers, cics

How can I read an OCCURS structure using a CICS CONTAINER?

I have a CICS program that call a webservice using the EXEC CICS INVOKE SERVICE instruction.
The webservice returns a container that has a list of product codes inside it.
It can return a variable number of product codes, so the copy of the container looks like this:

```
       01 RESP-CONTAINER.
          03 ServiceResponse.
             06 TABLE-PRODUCTS-num        PIC S9(9) COMP-5 SYNC.
             06 TABLE-PRODUCTS.
                09 LIST-PRODUCTS-num      PIC S9(9) COMP-5 SYNC.
                09 LIST-PRODUCTS-cont     PIC X(16).

       01 RESP-LIST-PRODUCTS.
          03 LIST-PRODUCTS.
             06 PRODUCT-CODE-num          PIC S9(9) COMP-5 SYNC.
             06 PRODUCT-CODE.
                09 PRODUCT-CODE2-length   PIC S9(4) COMP-5 SYNC.
                09 PRODUCT-CODE2          PIC  X(255).
```

I managed to call the webservice properly, but I can't read more than the first product code.

I tried to use the following instructions:

```
           EXEC CICS
             PUT CONTAINER  (WS-CONTAINER-NAME)
             CHANNEL        (WS-CHANNEL-NAME)
             FROM           (REQ-CONTAINER)
             FLENGTH        (LENGTH OF REQ-CONTAINER)
           END-EXEC.

           EXEC CICS
             INVOKE SERVICE (WS-WEBSERVICE-NAME)
             CHANNEL        (WS-CHANNEL-NAME)
             URIMAP         (WS-WEBSERVICE-NAME)
             OPERATION      (WS-OPERATION-NAME)
           END-EXEC.

           EXEC CICS
             GET CONTAINER  (WS-CONTAINER-NAME)
             CHANNEL        (WS-CHANNEL-NAME)
             INTO           (RESP-CONTAINER)
             FLENGTH        (LENGTH OF RESP-CONTAINER)
           END-EXEC.

      *--> Calculate the length of the product codes area
           COMPUTE WS-LEN-TOT = LIST-PRODUCTS-num *
                                LENGTH OF RESP-LIST-PRODUCTS.

           PERFORM
           VARYING IX FROM 1 BY 1
             UNTIL IX GREATER LIST-PRODUCTS-num

      *        --> Calculate the length of already read product codes
                   COMPUTE WS-LEN-READ = (LIST-PRODUCTS-num - IX + 1) *
                                          LENGTH OF RESP-LIST-PRODUCTS

      *        --> Calculate the offset of the next product code to be read
                   COMPUTE WS-OFFSET    =  WS-LEN-TOT - WS-LEN-READ + 1

      *        --> Read the next product code
                   EXEC CICS
                    GET CONTAINER  (LIST-PRODUCTS-cont)
                        CHANNEL    (WS-CHANNEL-NAME)
                        INTO       (RESP-LIST-PRODUCTS)
                        FLENGTH    (LENGTH OF RESP-LIST-PRODUCTS)
                        BYTEOFFSET (WS-OFFSET)
                   END-EXEC

      *        --> Display the product code
                   DISPLAY 'INDEX = ' IX
                   DISPLAY 'PRODUCT-CODE = ' PRODUCT-CODE2

           END-PERFORM.
```

This snippet only manages to display the first product of the list.
Howerer the loop works well, because it displays the product code as many times as the number of products, but it displays only the first.
How can I make this program work, so I can read all of the product codes?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually there is some documentation in the generated copybooks on how to get the information from response containers. Is there none in your copybooks?

Comment: Yes there are some. One in particular says: `The CONTAINER must be read from and written to in BIT mode.` How can I do so?

Comment: You can write data to a container in either modes CHAR or BIT by specifying either CHAR or BIT in the EXEC CICS PUT CONTAINER statement (see https://ibm.co/2m19Pm9). Writing in BIT mode ensures the data will not be converted when read from the container.
You cannot read data in BIT or CHAR mode; the mode the data was written in determines how it will be read again.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I can read the first OCCURS, so I suppose that the problem isn't the format of the data, but just to point to the next ones, but I don't know how.

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer for this?